# How to use JQuery to highlight text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="person">
Mike Mulky
</div>

<div class="person">
Jenny Sun
</div>

<div class="person">
Jack Kickle
</div>
```

This JQuery thingy will actually filter the matching query. For example, when a user types in a textbox.

```
$('#userInputTextbox').keypress(function(){
    $('div.person').hide().filter(':contains("'+THE_QUERY+'")').show();
});
```

This works! And it actually filters out the stuff.  My question is: how do you **highlight the words** that appear in there (the query and the matching text in the DIVs)?

Comment: By highlight do you mean changing the style (ie bg colour) or select the text ready for copying?

Comment: Given that he's in a `keypress` event, he presumably wants to change a color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd grab the [jQuery highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) for this.  Using it in a project now to reflect AJAX search results, works great and very light/simple.

In your case just add `.highlight(THE_QUERY)` in the chain.

```
$('#userInputTextbox').keypress(function(){
    $('div.person').hide().removeHighlight()
      .filter(':contains("'+THE_QUERY+'")').highlight(THE_QUERY).show();
});
```

Concept is easy, find the text wrap it in a `<span class="highlight"></span>`, you can style `.highlight` however you want.  There's a `.removeHighlight()` to match of course.

Answer (score 0):

For a lenient jQuery highlight plugin you may want to consider http://frightanic.com/web-authoring/lenient-jquery-highlight-plugin/